# DLL load failed while importing libtorrent: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

import libtorrent

---

ImportError

Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import libtorrent

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libtorrent: The specified module could not be found.

I am getting this error while importing libtorrent.. plz someone help me to solve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to install or reinstall **libtorrent** using pip.

Comment: I tried many times sir but its not working. i am getting same error

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows?

Comment: i am using Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

for windows, you need to build the libtorrent instead of installing from pip -https://libtorrent.org/python_binding.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).